# Why are language files not being picked up?

Tags: language, joomla-3.4, translation

I am manually translating some language files from en-GB to ca-ES (just the front-ends). Once translated and properly renamed, I place them in language/ca-ES but they are not picked up by my Joomla system. Am I missing something? It's happening all the time, so I guess I am. Can you help?
Thanks!

Dani

Comment: I assume you are either setting the default language to Spanish or have a language switcher option available?

Comment: Yes, also the files are saved as UTF-8 without BOM

Comment: Did you enable the language file debug in BE?

Comment: No, I haven't. I'll try it Valentin

Answer (score 2):

Enable language debug to see what is going on.

The problem could be that your template has language override. So check your

```
/templates/template_name/languages
```

folder to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

Any typo, a missing `“` or an unescaped link for example, will mean the whole file is ignored so you should check that. You can check if the file is being picked up, or not, with just a single entry of course. If it does work with a single simple entry then you have a typo somewhere in your full version.